# Is eager thread_local initialization possible in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, lazy-initialization, thread-local, static-initialization

[basic.stc.thread] states that "A variable with thread storage duration shall be initialized **before its first odr-use** (6.2) and, if constructed, shall be destroyed on thread exit."

Does this preclude an implementation initializing a namespace-scope `thread_local` variable eagerly upon thread creation, and do any major compilers support any mechanism to force this via some annotation?

I have a very small number of performance-critical `__thread` vars I would like to keep free of the per-access lazy init checks that `thread_local` normally incurs, but I currently need to do setup/teardown via separate calls in order to stay within `__thread` restrictions on non-trivial destructors, etc. Can I get `thread_local` with guaranteed eager construction/destruction for every thread and no lazy init testing?

Failing that, what is the cleanest known pattern for dealing with `__thread` setup/teardown call registration?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you dealing with a small set of critical variables, or do you need an infinitely expandable registration process? Both at once makes no sense.

Comment: Good question.  When I have questions like this, I write a trivial implementation in godbolt and analyse the assembly.

Comment: @groovyspaceman, While writing an answer for this, I just did that and it's not very helpful in this case: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EaZ9cp The issue is that a lot of the codegen will happen in the linker.

Comment: @Frank, I would like an extensible system, and I was just trying to head off conversation sidetracking about "lazy init being there for a reason". I am not the only developer for this product/platform, and other devs would certainly be happier the less centralized the registration mechanism is.

Comment: @Jeff The thing is, especially in a large-ish project, the idea of forcing many  thread locals to be instantiated in every thread, regardless of usage, makes me a bit uncomfortable. It can make sense for a small specific set of variables as an engineering compromise, but as a compromise, I wouldn't want to make it easy to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get `thread_local` with guaranteed eager construction/destruction for every thread and no lazy init testing?

Unlikely.

> Failing that, what is the cleanest known pattern for dealing with `__thread` setup/teardown call registration?

You can pack all your thread-specific information into one object accessed through one thread-specific pointer which gets initialized at thread start. E.g.:

```
struct ThreadContext {
    thread_local static ThreadContext* instance;

    ThreadContext() {
        assert(!instance);
        instance = this;
    }

    ~ThreadContext() {
        instance = 0;
    }

    ThreadContext(ThreadContext const&) = delete;
    ThreadContext& operator=(ThreadContext const&) = delete;
};

thread_local ThreadContext* ThreadContext::instance = 0;

void thread_function() {
    ThreadContext context;

    // Access it elsewhere as:
    ThreadContext::instance;  
}

ThreadContext* getThisThreadContext() {
    return ThreadContext::instance;  
    // No init check here. Just one move:
    // mov rax, QWORD PTR fs:ThreadContext::instance@tpoff
}
```